# Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'.ts(2339)

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

[image]

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/Karthick_Aadhi/example/src/app/app.module.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2339",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof NgbModule'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 15,
    "startColumn": 15,
    "endLineNumber": 15,
    "endColumn": 22
}
```

Comment: `NgbModule.forRoot()` is used in a very old version of ng-bootstrap with an old version of Angular (I think that in Angular 6 and ng-bootstrap 2.0). Check the version of ng-bootstrap you're using

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Importing any ng-bootstrap module via .forRoot() has now been completely removed since [5.0.0-rc.0](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/26073705ea17b87117b2d5a079779a341a6ed84f/CHANGELOG.md)

Change

```
NgbModule.forRoot()
```

To

```
NgbModule
```

Answer (score 0):

**In latest bootstrap version:**

`NgbModule.forRoot()` Reaplace  `NgbModule`

So, you can used `NgbModule` instead of `NgbModule.forRoot()` without any issue.